# Ubuntu Server HWE Kernel future releases

Tags: server, kernel, hardware-acceleration, hardware-enablement-stack

I’m running a Media Server on a Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04 with HWE kernel 5.8 (latest). The thing is that my cpu is an intel 11th gen, and the integrated GPU is being detected/claimed by Ubuntu only after kernel 5.11.
As I don’t want to use the testing ppa and install that kernel manually, Im wondering if I have a way to check when the kernel 5.11 or above, is planned  to be pushed/released via HWE.

Thanks in advance!
J'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the kernel in the current releases of Ubuntu.

The same kernel will be in HWE three months later.

```
Kernel         Release               20.04 HWE
5.8         20.10 (Oct 2020)     20.04.2 (Jan 2021)
5.11        21.04 (Apr 2021)     20.04.3 (Jul 2021)
```

However, this applies only to the most recent LTS release of Ubuntu. Older LTS HWE ceases when a newer LTS becomes available.

```
Release   Original Kernel  Highest HWE Kernel        
16.04 LTS     4.4               4.15
18.04 LTS     4.15              5.4
20.04 LTS     5.4               5.8 (HWE still active until 22.04)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I didn't know.